# Laravel - displaying multiple images in blade

Tags: mysql, laravel, image

How to display multiple images in my `products.blade.php`
Here is my `ProductsController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('products')->with('products', $products);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('createprod');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input=$request->all();
        $images=array();
        if($files=$request->file('images')){
            foreach($files as $file){
                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move('storage/image',$name);
                $images[]=$name;
            }
        }
        /*Insert your data*/

        Product::insert( [
            'images'=>  implode("|",$images),
            'title' =>$input['title'],
            //you can put other insertion here
        ]);

        return redirect('/products');
    }
}
```

And this is my `products.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">All products
                    <a href="/products/create" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 70%">New product +</a></div>
                <hr>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                        <h2>{{$product->title}}</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <img style="width:100%" src="/storage/image/{{$product->images}}">
                        <br>
                        <hr>
                    @endforeach
                    <small><?php echo now() ?></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

When I upload just one image it shows on my blade but when I try to upload more it shows broken image icon. I hope somebody will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $product->images is held as a string imploded with |, when you have more than one image you need to explode these (on the controller/model level or on blade's) and loop over them in the blade template.

So instead `<img style="width:100%" src="/storage/image/{{$product->images}}">`
you would need something like:

```
@foreach (explode('|', $product->images) as $image)
    <img style="width:100%" src="/storage/image/{{$image}}">
@endforeach
```

**TIP** If I were you, I would read about Laravel Eloquent Mutators. I think they would make your life much easier. You would have a mutator that would implode your pictures on the fly when you create/save a model and explode when you retrive it from the database.

Comment: A link to the Mutators' documentation https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators